# Charms&Enchantments conundrum

Tags: harry-potter, magical-theory

Is there any difference between charming objects (i.e. "adding or changing certain properties of an object") and enchanting them?

Is charming/enchantment used in creation of magical objects?

Do runes play any part in this?

I'd prefer canon answer if possible.

Comment: Sense of the words I get from non-HP universes:  You do a charm to create an enchantment.  No clue whether it applies here.

Answer (score 1):

A charm is specifically applied to an object or being. Such as the Fidelius Charm(Invisibility used on Harry in book 5) or Warnd-lgihting Charm(Lumos).

An enchantment is something that can be applied to anything, even "thin air". And what I mean by thin air is the Protego Totalum(Book 7, used by Hermione at several campsites) and Priori Incantatum(Harry vs Voldemort at the end of Book 4). Additionally, charms are a subset of enchantments.

An analogy to biological classification: If a charm is equal to a Phylum, then an Enchantment is equal to a Kingdom.

---

It should also be noted there are more types of enchantments than just charms. Like Repello Inimicum(disintegrates objects that pass a certain threshold) would not fall under a charm because it doesn't require a physical presence(object or being) to have the spell take affect. Instead Repello Inimicum is a field around an area.

Answer (score 0):

I believe an enchantment is usually (possibly always) a charm spell itself - the Harry Potter Wiki lists Protective Enchantments as a type of charm, for example. The Harry Potter Wiki page on [spells has a classification section](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Spell#Classification), but it only mentions charms and not enchantments.

That same link says that charms have "long-lasting effects" when cast by an experienced practitioner, so charms could be used in the creation of magical objects, if you mean creating a magical object out of a non-magical one.

Transfiguration is also likely to be used in the creation of a magical object - it has a branch called conjuration where "the desired object is seemingly transfigured out of thin air." However, J.K. Rowling has said: ["There is legislation about what you can conjure and what you can't. Something that you conjure out of thin air will not last."](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/0700-swns-alfie.htm)

Runes do not appear to be used in  the creation of magical objects, but rather as a stand-in for Latin alphabet characters.

Comment: Yeah... I did a little canon info digging, and Runes (unfortunately) appear to be nothing more than an alphabet of a dead language(s). So no 'runic magic' :(